# TSQL to perform aggregation with Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My sample data source is following

```
declare @t1 as table
               (
                   sn int,
                   site varchar(max),
                   cond varchar(max),
                   val int
               )

insert into @t1
   select *
   from
       (values
            (1, 'site1', 'X', 100),
            (2, 'site1', 'Y', 200),
            (3, 'site1', 'Z', 300),
            (1, 'site2', 'A', 100),
            (2, 'site2', 'B', 200),
            (3, 'site2', 'C', 300),
            (1, 'site3', 'X', 100),
            (2, 'site3', 'P', 200),
            (3, 'site3', 'Q', 300),
            (1, 'site4', 'A', 100),
            (2, 'site4', 'Y', 200),
            (3, 'site4', 'Q', 300),
            (1, 'site5', 'E', 100), 
            (1, 'site5', 'E', 1000),
            (2, 'site5', 'F', 200),
            (3, 'site5', 'G', 300)
         ) t (a, b, c, d)
```

I want SQL to check if there exists any row with `cond=X` or `cond=Y` by site and if yes, don't perform any aggregation; if no, perform a sum of val.

I am currently achieving it by following

`Method1`

```
select  
    ax.sn, ax.site, ax.cond,
    sum(ax.revisedVal) as revisedTotal
from
    (select distinct 
         a.sn, a.site, a.cond, a.val, t.one, m.revisedVal
     from 
         @t1 a
     outer apply
         (select * 
          from 
              (select *, 1 as one 
               from @t1 b 
               where b.cond = 'Y' or b.cond = 'X') x 
          where a.site = x.site) t
     outer apply 
         (values (case when t.one = 1 then null else a.val end)) m(revisedVal))ax
group by 
    ax.sn, ax.site, ax.cond
order by 
    ax.site, ax.sn
```

`Method 2`

```
SELECT a.sn,
       a.site,
       a.cond,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN a.site = x.site THEN a.val
             ELSE NULL
           END) AS revisedVal
FROM   @t1 a
       OUTER apply (SELECT b.site
                    FROM   (SELECT site
                            FROM   @t1
                            WHERE  cond <> 'X'
                                    OR cond <> 'Y'
                            EXCEPT
                            SELECT site
                            FROM   @t1
                            WHERE  cond = 'X'
                                    OR cond = 'Y') b
                    WHERE  a.site = b.site) x
GROUP  BY a.site,
          a.sn,
          a.cond
```

I was wondering if there is any better way of achieving this.

**Edit**

Desired Result

```
| sn | site  | cond | revisedTotal |
|----|-------|------|--------------|
| 1  | site1 | X    | NULL         |
| 2  | site1 | Y    | NULL         |
| 3  | site1 | Z    | NULL         |
| 1  | site2 | A    | 100          |
| 2  | site2 | B    | 200          |
| 3  | site2 | C    | 300          |
| 1  | site3 | X    | NULL         |
| 2  | site3 | P    | NULL         |
| 3  | site3 | Q    | NULL         |
| 1  | site4 | A    | NULL         |
| 2  | site4 | Y    | NULL         |
| 3  | site4 | Q    | NULL         |
| 1  | site5 | E    | 1100         |
| 2  | site5 | F    | 200          |
| 3  | site5 | G    | 300          |
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

… [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b9bab41ba2df95f575f7a52e41def55)

```
select ax.sn, ax.site, ax.cond, sum(case when ax.one = 1 then null else ax.val end) as revisedTotal
from
(
select *, max(case when cond in ('Y', 'X') then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by site) as one
from @t1
) as ax
group by ax.sn, ax.site, ax.cond
order by ax.site, ax.sn;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a `having` clause on an aggregation query:

```
select site, sum(val)
from @t t
group by site
having sum(case when cond = X or cond = Y then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

EDIT:

```
with agg as (
      select site, sum(val) as val
      from @t t
      group by site
      having sum(case when cond = X or cond = Y then 1 else 0 end) = 0
     )
select site, val
from agg
union all
select site, val
from @t t
where not exists (select 1 from agg where agg.site = t.site);
```

Comment: thanks for this, but this solution only returns the result set for site2 and site5 . I want the final query to show all the sites with aggregation taking place only for site2 and site5 where the other sites should show null for the aggregation column. I want the final results to be returned same as my query result. If I alter the code to `select t.sn,t.site,t.cond, sum(val) as reviseVal from @t1 t group by t.sn,t.site,t.cond having sum(case when cond='X' or cond='Y' then 1 else 0 end)=0 order by site,sn asc`

Comment: it does not ignore site1, site3, site4 for aggregation. It is only ignoring the rows with `cond=X and cond=Y` for those sites. I want these sites to be completely ignored since there exists at least one row for each of those sites with that `cond`. I want these sites to be returned in the final result set but with aggregated value as `null` for those sites. How can that be made happen?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT t1.site, SUM(t1.val)
from @t1 t1
left join @t1 t2 on t2.site=t1.site and t2.cond in ('X','Y')
where t2.site is null
group by t1.site;
```

Produces the sum for all values of `val`, per site, where there does not exist a `val` with the value 'X' or 'Y'.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=340adffb3d5fd901ca22da0fab07d1b6)

or, with the other columns added:

```
SELECT t1.sn, t1.site, t1.cond, SUM(t1.val)
from @t1 t1
left join @t1 t2 on t2.site=t1.site and t2.cond in ('X','Y')
where t2.site is null
group by t1.sn, t1.site, t1.cond;
```